# UML Multi-Instance State Machine Visualisation

Tags: uml, state-machine, multiple-instances

I was wondering if you could help me clarify two aspects regarding multi-instance state machines.

**First question**

Consider an example state machine [*SM1*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btTgK.png) containing one state *A*:

[image]

On the left, transition *start* creates a new instance of the state machine. Transition *stop* terminates the instance. 
There can be multiple instances of state machine *SM1* running in parallel, e.g. 5 instances.

Now, what I want is a transition that would terminate ALL state machine *SM1* instances that are running at the given time.
E.g. we create five state machines *A* and then transition *stopALL* would terminate ALL of them at once.

Is such behaviour permitted by UML specification? If yes, is there a graphical notation to unambiguously represent such a behaviour? I could not find the answer in the UML specification document.

**Second question**

Consider a multi-instance state machine [*SM2*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxtMU.png) with state *A* and one transition *startStop*: [image]

The behaviour of the transition is as follows: upon firing, the transition creates a new instance of *SM2* and terminates an existing one.

Is such behaviour permitted by the specification? Is there an unambiguous graphical way to express such a behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special UML method but standard UML tools are absolutely sufficient. You need to broadcast a terminate signal (on state machine diagram you can represent it by behaviour on a transition that should terminate other instances). Then you just need to model that on terminate reception the state machine goes to final state.

### Terminate All Example

[image: EndTerminate]
Note that the behaviour after slash (/) is a behaviour invoked on a state transition i.e. when a state machine changes it's state into final the behaviour sendStopAllSignal is invoked which in turn should be described on a class diagram (with probably corresponding activity diagram)
Similarly you need to have a receiveStopAllSignal behaviour included in class diagram.

### Terminate Existing At Start

[image: StartTerminate]
This is similar situation - you need to have both sendStopSignal and receiveStopSignal modelled elsewhere.

Note however that such naming convention (sendAbcSignal for behaviour of sending/broadcasting signal Abc and receiveAbcSignal for behaviour as a reaction to Abc signal reception) is quite common, useful and self-explanatory (i.e. you probably won't model a separate action diagrams for those behaviours unless some extra logic is needed there).

Comment: Thanks Ister, it would be terrific. Could you please point me to the OMG UML spec where they talk about the broadcasting signals? I see only class-related info and nothing state machine -related.

Comment: Search for BroadcastSignalAction and/or SignalBroadcastAction (well...) in OMG's UML spec.

Comment: So as I understand from the first paragraph in 13.3.3.2, this is part of the textual notation rather than graphical. In fact, graphically this behaviour is cannot event be explicitly expressed.

Comment: While this looks like a small change compared to your diagrams it has significant difference in meaning as it shows that the action is triggered at the transition. Moreover if you want to explicitly model that the signal is broadcast you need to use other diagrams for that, like interaction diagrams.

Comment: Thanks very much Ister. You made it very clear for me.